# validar objeto pasado como parámetro

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tengo una consigna para una función que recibe como parámetro un **objeto** y debe devolver otro objeto con las **propiedades cambiadas a valores**.

La función debe validar que si recibe un **número** retorne un error, igualmente para un **string**, un **array**, *para que reciba solo* **objetos**.

Al momento de pasarle un **objeto** me lo valida como si recibiera un **array**. Leí que el tipo de `array` es objeto igual que objeto y tengo la duda como validarlo.

Este es mi código:

```js
function reverseKeys(input){
  if(typeof input === "number") {
    return "error, input can't be a number"
  }
  if(typeof input === "string") {
    return "error, input can't be an String"
  }
  if(typeof input !== Array.isArray(input)){
    return "error, input can't be an Array"
  }
  if(typeof input === 'object') {
    return "esto es un objeto"
  }
}

console.log(reverseKeys(444)); // error, input can't be a number

console.log(reverseKeys('hello')); // error, input can't be an String

console.log(reverseKeys([1,2,3])); // error, input can't be an Array

console.log(reverseKeys({})); // error, input can't be an String
```

Comment: Los tres últimos console logs no tiene bien cerrados los paréntesis, ¿seguro que te funcionan?

Comment: estaban mal editados aqui, pero si esta funcionando el codigo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo estabas teniendo con el tercer `if`:

```
if(typeof input !== Array.isArray(input)){
  return "error, input can't be an Array"
}
```

Esa condición lo que está haciendo es preguntar si `typeof input` que devuelve `'object'` (porque para Javascript los arrays son un objeto. De ahí la existencia de la función `isArray()`) es distinto a `Array.isArray(input)` (que devuelve `true`). Te estaría entrando el código por esta función le enviases lo que le enviases, pero como la condición para `number` y `string` están antes, te salías de la función antes de llegar a ella.

Como debería ser esa condición es:

```
if(Array.isArray(input)){
  return "error, input can't be an Array"
}
```

Puesto que la función `isArray()` te devuelve `true` en caso de que el objeto evaluado sea un `array` y `false` en caso de que no lo sea.

```js
function reverseKeys(input){
  if(typeof input === "number") {
    return "error, input can't be a number"
  }
  if(typeof input === "string") {
    return "error, input can't be an String"
  }
  if(Array.isArray(input)){
    return "error, input can't be an Array"
  }
  if(typeof input === 'object') {
    return "esto es un objeto"
  }
}

console.log(reverseKeys(444)); // error, input can't be a number

console.log(reverseKeys('hello')); // error, input can't be an String

console.log(reverseKeys([1,2,3])); // error, input can't be an Array

console.log(reverseKeys({ nombre: 'hola' })); // error, input can't be an String
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que `null` también es considerado un objeto, así que si hacemos algo como `console.log(reverseKeys(null))`, este fácilmente pasará la validación y lo que sea que haya adentro que trabaje con objetos dará un error. De misma manera pasa con muchos otros valores.

Comment: Así es. Tan solo trataba de hacerle ver al OP donde estaba encontrándose el problema de su evaluación para `object` le entrase por la condición de su evaluación para `array`. La pregunta parecía requerir la respuesta a esa cuestión.

Comment: ok , me queda claro esta función, ahora si valida los objetos, y ya puedo ejecutar mi funcion despues de validar el objeto. gracias por la explicacion.

Answer (score 3):

Es mucho más fácil que complicarte la vida con `typeof`, solo convierte el tipo nativo del parámetro a un string, usando `Object.toString` y te devolverá una pastilla como la siguiente `[object (tipo)]`

```js
function reverseKeys(input){
  // Si "input" es undefined por cualquier motivo
  // El valor de regreso no hará sentido, por lo que pondremos uno propio.
  if (input === undefined) return "error, input can't be a undefined value";
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === "[object Object]") {
    // ...
    return "this is a valid object";
  } else {
    const nativeType = typeof input;
    return "error, input can't be a"+(nativeType === "object" ? input === null ? " null value" : "n Array" : " "+nativeType[0].toUpperCase() + nativeType.slice(1));
    // Un array o null daran "object"
    // Lo validaremos en ambos casos
  }
}

console.log(reverseKeys(444)); // error, input can't be a number
console.log(reverseKeys('hello')); // error, input can't be an String
console.log(reverseKeys([1,2,3])); // error, input can't be an Array
console.log(reverseKeys(null)); // error, input can't be a null value
console.log(reverseKeys(undefined)); // error, input can't be a null value
console.log(reverseKeys({})) // this is a valid object;
```

Estamos usando un operador ternario para evitar usar un condicional tradicional y alargar tanto el código

Referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Por otra parte, una vez tenemos el string del tipo al mismo string, pero con la primera letra mayúscula, usando [`String.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) para eliminar la primera letra con la finalidad de concatenar ese string primero solo con la primera letra para convertirla a mayúscula con `toUpperCase`, obtendremos la primera letra usando los corchetes de indexación, obteniendo el primer elemento, que en un string será la primera letra.